# Parsing JSON in Swfit 3.0 Cast NSArray to NSDictionary Error

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to parse a JSON Url into a UICollectionView, but I keep getting Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x1010ebd88) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1010ec288). as an error when I try to load the data. I am using xcode 8 with Swift 3.0. Can anybody see the error I am getting and how to fix it? Not sure where to go from here.

```
    let link = "http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=swimming&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"

    let urlString = link

    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            do {

                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                let currentConditions = parsedData["items"] as! [String:Any]

                print(currentConditions)

                let currentItem = currentConditions["link"] as! [String:Any]
                print(currentItem)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        }.resume()
```

Edit: OK So I have gone this far and now within "items", there is another string that I need to extract into an array. Within items, there are several "link = " I need the link in an array, but not sure how to get it out. When I print the key value, the items show up, but it seems to be just one long string, not in an array or dictionary. Any advice? Thanks,

```
            let urlString = link
    var itemArray: Any?
    var parsedData: [String:Any] = ["":""]

    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            do {

                parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                itemArray = parsedData["items"] as! [[String:Any]]



                for (key, value) in parsedData {
                    print("\(key) - \(value) ")
                }



            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        }.resume()

    guard let images_array = parsedData["items"] as? NSArray else
    {
        print("error2")
        return
    }
```

Comment: In your JSON, `parsedData["items"]` is an array, not a dictionary so you should be casting it to `[[String:Any]]`.  `currentConditions["link"]` is also not a dictionary, it's a `String`.

Comment: OK That helped to print currentConditions. now, it is not letting me pull out "link" from currentConditions even when I set it to string. the code I updated to let currentItem = currentConditions["link"] as! String  That is now sending an error of cannot subscript a value of type [[String:Any]] with an index of type 'String'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this : 
Since the data in items is array of dictionaries and link is not in internal array it is main dictionary so you can easily get this by passing link in as key.

```
 let link = "http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=swimming&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"

        let urlString = link

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                do {

                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                    let currentConditions = parsedData["items"] as! [[String:Any]]

                    print(currentConditions)

                    let currentItem = parsedData["link"] as! String
                    print(currentItem)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            }.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `parsedData["items"]` is an array and the value for key `link` is a string, so you need to use a loop:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any] // for convenience

...

if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data!, options: []) as? JSONDictionary {
        // print(jsonData)
        guard let currentConditions = parsedData["items"] as? [JSONDictionary] else { return }
        for condition in currentConditions {
            print(condition["link"] as! String)
        }
    }
}
```